# Multi Dimensional Array Table for Weekly Sales Report, NEED HELP ON INPUT

Tags: arrays

Write a program that stores the weekly (Monday thru Friday) sales totals for three salespersons. Your program should allow the user to enter the sales amounts and print a sales report with headings, the daily totals for each salesperson (your two-dimensional array), the calculated weekly totals for each sales person and the calculated totals for the day of each salesperson. In addition, create a single-dimensional array of Strings representing the days of the week (Monday-Friday) using an initializer list. Your program output should look like the following:

Input Screen

Enter Monday Totals for Salesperson 1: 10.00

Enter Tuesday Totals for Salesperson 1: 20.00

Enter Wednesday Totals for Salesperson 1: 30.00
(etc.)

Enter Monday Totals for Salesperson 2: 60.00
(etc.)

Output Screen

Weekly Sales Report

```
Mon Tue Wed Thurs   Fri     Total
```

1    10.00  20.00   30.00   40.00   50.00       150.00

2    60.00  70.00   80.00   90.00   10.00       310.00

3    20.00  30.00   40.00   50.00   60.00       200.00

---

90.00   120.00 150.00   180.00  120.00      660.00

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimArray
{
public static void main( String [] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    // 1) Declare and allocate Storage

    String [] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    double [][] saleTotals = new double [3][5];

    // 2) Populate Array

   for (int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
    {
      System.out.print( "Enter " + days[j] + " Totals for Salesperson " +      (i+1) + ": " + "  " );
      saleTotals[i][j] = scan.nextDouble( );

    }

     // 3) Process Array - Accumulators
    double total = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
        total += saleTotals[i][j];



    System.out.println( );
    System.out.println(" Weekly Sales Report ");

     // 4) Output Array
    for ( int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
    {
         System.out.println();
        for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
        {
        System.out.print(saleTotals[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }

    System.out.println( );
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");


    System.out.println( total);
```

NEED HELP ON TOTALS FOR EACH ROW AND COLUMN AND HOW TO OUTPUT IT

Answer (score 1):

Understanding from your question, what your requesting is that you want the input inquiries to display the proper names of the day and the salesperson printed respectively while asking for their input. So your code would be as such:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimArray
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

        // 1) Declare and allocate Storage

        //Each day name is assigned to the array as a String so each name must be enclosed in apostrophes and each string must be separated by commas.
        String [] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
        double [][] saleTotals = new double [3][5];

        // 2) Populate Array

        for (int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
            {
                //days[j] will print the proper day and "(i+1)" will print the proper salesperson number
                System.out.print( "Enter " + days[j] + " Totals for Salesperson " + (i+1) + ": " + "    " );
                saleTotals[i][j] = scan.nextDouble( );
            }
        }
        System.out.println( );
        System.out.println(" Weekly Sales Report ");

        // 4) Output Array
        for ( int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println();
            for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
            {
                System.out.print(saleTotals[i][j] + "\t");
            }
        }

        System.out.println( );
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: how would i get the totals for rows and coloumns?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the total of each salesperson to be printed at the end of each row, all you have to do is to add the values of the current row and print it after all the values of the row have been printed. So you would use a double variable and you would set it to 0 (empty it) after printing every row. During the row printing you can add each sales value to the "total" till the end, after which you print the accumulated total of that row. This can be exemplified with the code:

```
// 4) Output Array
double total;
for ( int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
{
    total = 0; // Set it to zero so u can start adding the new row
    for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
    {
        System.out.print(saleTotals[i][j] + "\t");
        total += saleTotals[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println(total); // After having printed all the value you print the accumulated total of that particular row
}
```